# Date split in R

Tags: r, date

I have a data frame like this:

```
Date
20130101
20130102
20130103
20130104
```

how i can split Date column in different column?
I have already used following function but it is not working :

```
library(data.table)  
setDT(DF)[, tstrsplit(DATE, "/|\\s", type.convert = TRUE)]
```

Comment: `tstrsplit` splits on existing characters in the string. I think what you want is either `?strptime` or `?as.IDate`, which will parse into a date; or `?substr`, which will let you select substrings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some solutions that do not require any packages.  They all produce a data.frame with a `"Date"` class column followed by numeric columns for year, month and day.  (The input used in reproducible form is given in the Note at the end.)

**1) POSIXlt** First convert the `Date` column to `"Date"` class giving `date` and then to an unclassed `"POSIXlt"` object giving `lt`.  Now pick off the elements of `lt` appropriately:

```
date <- as.Date(as.character(DF$Date), format = "%Y%m%d")
lt <- unclass(as.POSIXlt(date))
with(lt, data.frame(Date = date, year = year + 1900, month = mon + 1, day = mday))
```

giving:

```
        Date year month day
1 2013-01-01 2013     1   1
2 2013-01-02 2013     1   2
3 2013-01-03 2013     1   3
4 2013-01-04 2013     1   4
```

**2) format**

```
data.frame(date = as.Date(as.character(DF$Date), format = "%Y%m%d"),
           year = as.numeric(format(date, "%Y")), 
           month = as.numeric(format(date, "%m")), 
           day = as.numeric(format(date, "%d")))
```

giving:

```
        date year month day
1 2013-01-01 2013     1   1
2 2013-01-02 2013     1   2
3 2013-01-03 2013     1   3
4 2013-01-04 2013     1   4
```

**3) math**

```
with(DF, data.frame(date = as.Date(as.character(DF$Date), format = "%Y%m%d"),
                    year = Date %/% 10000, 
                    month = Date %% 10000 %/% 100, 
                    day = Date %% 100))
```

giving:

```
        date year month day
1 2013-01-01 2013     1   1
2 2013-01-02 2013     1   2
3 2013-01-03 2013     1   3
4 2013-01-04 2013     1   4
```

**4) read.fwf**

```
data.frame(date = as.Date(as.character(DF$Date), format = "%Y%m%d"),
           read.fwf(textConnection(as.character(DF$Date)), c(4, 2, 2),
                    col.names = c("year", "month", "day")))
```

giving:

```
        date year month day
1 2013-01-01 2013     1   1
2 2013-01-02 2013     1   2
3 2013-01-03 2013     1   3
4 2013-01-04 2013     1   4
```

**5) sub/read.table**

```
date.ch <- sub("(....)(..)(..)", "\\1-\\2-\\3", DF$Date)
data.frame(date = as.Date(date.ch), 
           read.table(text = date.ch, col.names = c("year", "month", "day"), sep = "-"))
```

giving:

```
        date year month day
1 2013-01-01 2013     1   1
2 2013-01-02 2013     1   2
3 2013-01-03 2013     1   3
4 2013-01-04 2013     1   4
```

**Note:** The input used, `"DF"`, in reproducible form is:

```
DF <- data.frame(Date = 20130101:20130104)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you not set on using `data.table` you could use the following command that incorporates `substr`:

```
x = data.frame("20130101", "20130102", "20130103", "20130104")

y<-data.frame(Year=substr(x[,1],1,4),
              Month=substr(x[,1],5,6),
              Day=substr(x[,1],7,8))
```

If you are sure your data is in the same format for the whole vector.

Comment: there's no reason you can't use `substr` in `data.table` too

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this with lubridate

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

data = 
  data_frame(Date = c(20130101, 20130102, 20130103, 20130104) ) %>%
  mutate(date = 
           Date %>%
           as.character %>% 
           ymd,
         year = year(date),
         month = month(date),
         day = day(date))
```